# Mysql where (in) statement of another table without joins

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, where-in

I have 2 tables, A and B, both have the same data expect for that the table B also has a 'include' column.

I want to select all a.code and a.user_id entries in table a expect if the same combination of A.user_id + A.code exists in table B where include is 1, then I don't want to return these values from table A.

First I tried to fix it with this:

```
SELECT a.code, a.user_id
LEFT JOIN B ON a.code = b.code
FROM A a WHERE b.include != 1
```

this didn't work because the code field exists multiple times in table B so I got to many results.

Eventually I came up with this, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution, or even correct.

```
SELECT a.code, a.user_id
FROM A a WHERE CONCAT(code, '-', user_id) 
IN (SELECT CONCAT(code, '-', user_id) FROM b WHERE include != 1
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Left join not working

Comment: U need record either code available in table B or not

Comment: U have multiple records in table B and u dont need them only one record required?

Comment: The left join here doesn't work because it multiplies the amount of results I get back when the same code is multiple times in table B.

I only need to know whether there exists a record with the same combination code + user_id and include = 1

Comment: Than u must add userid also in join conditions

Comment: I don't get why your first query doesn't work... And have you tried using `SELECT DISTINCT(a.code, a.user_id)` or something similar to remove duplicates ?

Comment: Yes his query is correct but he need combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do that

Excluding LEFT JOIN:

```sql
SELECT a.code, a.user_id
FROM A a 
LEFT JOIN B
  ON  a.code    = b.code 
  AND a.user_id = b.user_id
  AND b.include = 1
WHERE b.user_id IS NULL
```

Or excluding subselect

```sql
SELECT a.code, a.user_id
FROM A a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM B b
  WHERE b.code    = a.code 
    AND b.user_id = a.user_id
    AND b.include = 1
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0118c/1

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what I was looking for, it returns more rows then the solution I had though.

Could you maybe explain why the first query works with where b.user_id IS NULL?

Comment: This is because of how `LEFT JOIN` works. If for a row in table `A` there is no such row in table `B` that meats the join criterias, all collumns from table `B` will contain `NULL`. If you modify the query to `SELECT * ...` without `WHERE ...`, you will see the unfiltered result of the `LEFT JOIN` ([sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0118c/5)). Now you can check any B-coulmn used in the JOIN-condition. If it is `NULL` - that is only possible if no row from table `B` was found for the given table `A` row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT a.code, a.user_id
LEFT JOIN B ON a.code = b.code AND a.user_id = b.user_id
FROM A a WHERE b.include != 1
```

This solution is equal to your second query.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get back over 2000 results while table A only has 1700 records.